# Is there any algebraic way to "invert" a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Sorry if my question is so vague, but my question is mainly the following:

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$ module $\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have this chain of submodules, $\mathbb{Z}\supsetneq 2\mathbb{Z}\supsetneq 4\mathbb{Z}\cdots\supsetneq 0$. Is there any algebraic action such that produces another module, say $R(\mathbb{Z})$, such that has a natural bijective correspondence with its submodules and the submodules of $\mathbb{Z}$, and such that if $F$ denotes the natural bijection, $F:\text{submodules of }\mathbb{Z}\to \text{submodules of }R(\mathbb{Z})$, then we get $F(\mathbb{Z})=0\subsetneq F(2\mathbb{Z})\subsetneq F(4\mathbb{Z})\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq F(0)=R(\mathbb{Z})$? So this is kind of "inverting" the module structure of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Please let me know if there is some similar algebraic action to the above idea!

Comment: There's an order-reversing correspondence $M \to \mathbb{Z}/M$, at least, but $\text{Hom}(M, \mathbb{Z}/M) = 0$ for any $M\subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Note that a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module is noetherian and cannot contain a strictly increasing infinite sequence of submodules. Hence, $R(\mathbb{Z})$ must be a rather unnatural construction.